# Examples of "too much of a good thing"?

Tags: shiurim-measurements

I can think of several examples of minimal requirements (*k'zayit, rov cos, arba tefachim*, etc.) and examples of unlimited measures (*ein lahem shiur*) but are there **examples of maximum requirements**, i.e. things that are permitted as long as they are not to excess (and, ideally, where those limits are defined)?

(And I know of Rabban Gamiel's series or More X, More Y, but I'm really after specific limits to a permitted action/experience.)

Comment: Owning chametz crumbs

Comment: Marrying *a* woman. (Even when polygamy was allowed - per a king “לא ירבה לו נשים”.)

Comment: Drinking on Purim?

Comment: Eating on Yom Kippur (in certain circumstances)?

Comment: Firm hat brims on Shabbat? (Assorted other Ohel Arai questions?)

Comment: Too much laughter and frivolity (Pirkei Avot). Too much eationg ("achilah gasa*).Being too much of a tzadik (I think it's in *Kohelet*?)

Comment: Too many Chulyot on your Tzitzit?

Comment: Tzedaka that makes you poor?

Comment: Making the whole dough Challah?

Comment: Rotting-spots on an Etrog?

Comment: More than one biah in certain cases of yibum ...

Comment: Distance you can walk on Shabbat?

Comment: Number of husbands dying before a woman can't remarry

Comment: Enumerating praises of God.

Comment: Aliyos on weekdays, fast days, Rosh Chodesh, and Chol Hamoed.

Comment: The entire second Perek of Erchin?

Comment: Going behind a woman by the river?

Comment: Someone want to source all of these and post a community wiki? At this point I’m tempted to VTC as too broad.

Answer (score 2):

In [Kedoshim 19:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.19.2?lang=bi&aliyot=0) the Ramban introduces the idea of a "[נבל ברשות התורה](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.19.2?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Ramban_on_Leviticus.19.2&lang2=bi)" (lit. a scoundrel with the permission of the Torah). While not an exact *shiur* that would uniformly apply to every person, we could say the Ramban sets forth a **maximum *shiur*** of earthly pleasures we need.

**Explaining the principle that we should minimize over-indulging**

> לפיכך בא הכתוב אחרי שפרט האיסורים שאסר אותם לגמרי וצוה בדבר כללי שנהיה פרושים מן המותרות ימעט במשגל
>
> Therefore, Scripture came, after it specified the prohibitions that it completely forbade, and commanded a more general [rule] - that we should be separated from [indulgence of] those things that are permissible:

**For example:  Sexual Relations**

> כענין שאמרו ([ברכות כב](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.22a.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) שלא יהיו תלמידי חכמים מצויין אצל נשותיהן כתרנגולין **ולא ישמש אלא כפי הצריך בקיום המצוה ממנו**
>
> He should minimize sexual relations, like the matter that they stated ([Berakhot 22a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.22a.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), "That Torah scholars should not be found with their wives [constantly] like chickens. **"And he should only have relations according to the need for his execution of the commandment."**

**Another example: Wine**

> ויקדש עצמו מן **היין במיעוטו** כמו שקרא הכתוב ([במדבר ו ה](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.6.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) הנזיר קדוש **ויזכור הרעות הנזכרות ממנו בתורה** ([בראשית ט כא](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.9.21?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) **בנח ובלוט**
>
> And he should sanctify himself from **wine by minimizing it** - just as Scripture calls the Nazarite, holy ([Numbers 6:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.6.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)); **and mentions the evil that comes from it in the Torah with Noach** ([Genesis 9:21](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.9.21?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) **and with Lot** ([Genesis 19:33](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.19.33?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Again not a standard set *shiur* like *k'zayis*, *rov cos*, or *arba tefachim*- but still a **"maximum" *shiur*** to be determined individually.

Comment: I’ve always heard נבל translates as a “disgusting person,” cognate to נבלה and נבל תבל.

Answer (score 2):

[Terumot 4:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Terumot.4.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> הַמַּרְבֶּה בִּתְרוּמָה,
>       רַבִּי אֱלִיעֶזֶר אוֹמֵר: אֶחָד מֵעֲשָׂרָה, כִּתְרוּמַת מַעֲשֵׂר.
>           יָתֵר מִכָּאן, יַעֲשֶׂנָּה תְּרוּמַת מַעֲשֵׂר לְמָקוֹם אַחֵר.
>       רַבִּי יִשְׁמָעֵאל אוֹמֵר: מֶחֱצָה חֻלִּין וּמֶחֱצָה תְּרוּמָה.
>       רַבִּי טַרְפוֹן וְרַבִּי עֲקִיבָא אוֹמְרִים: עַד שֶׁיְּשַׁיֵּר שָׁם חֻלִּין.‏
>
> One who gives more Terumah: Rabbi Eliezer says: [he may give up to] one out of ten, as in the case of Terumat Ma'aser [a portion of the tithes that is given to the priest]. [If he gave] more than this, he must make [the extra into] Terumat Ma'aser for other produce. Rabbi Yishmael says: [he may give up until the mixture is] half Chulin [non-sacred produce] and half Terumah. Rabbi Tarfon and Rabbi Akiva say: [he may give] as long as there remains [enough to carry] the name of Chulin.

[Bava Kamma 9a-b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.9a.20-9b.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> ‏א"ר זירא אמר רב הונא במצוה עד שליש מאי שליש
>   ... אלא אמר ר' זירא בהידור מצוה עד שליש במצוה‏
>
> Rabbi Zera said for a mitzvah up to one third. [For instance, if a regular etrog costs $6, you can buy a mehudar etrog for $8 (6/3) or $9 (6 + 9/3 = 9)]. But the next opinion in gemara refutes the prohibition to add more, and contrarily says that more than 1/3 will lead God to reimburse you in this world.

To eat out of the Sukkah up to 2-3 eggs equivalent volume of food ([Sukkah 26a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.26a.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

> אוכלין ושותין ארעי חוץ לסוכנות..... ..וכמה אכילת עראי אמר רב יוסף תרתי או תלת ביעי.‏

There are more- to eat before *b'dikas chameitz*, to drink wine before *tefila* or *din*...

Comment: Dollars in the Talmud. Cool.

Answer (score 2):

[Mishne Torah Suka 4:1](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/946097/jewish/Shofar-Sukkah-vLulav-Chapter-Four.htm) (see also [here](https://www.etzion.org.il/en/dimensions-sukka-0))

> These are the required measurements of a sukkah: Its height should not
>   be less than ten handbreadths **nor more than twenty cubits**.

[Mishne Torah Melakhim 3:2](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188347/jewish/Melachim-uMilchamot-Chapter-3.htm)

> [A king] should not amass many wives (Deuteronomy 17:17). The Oral Tradition
>   states that he may take **no more than eighteen wives**.

[Mishne Torah Melakhim 3:3](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188347/jewish/Melachim-uMilchamot-Chapter-3.htm)

> **[A king] may not accumulate many horses**, only what is necessary for his
>   cavalry . It is even forbidden for him to have one additional horse to
>   run before him as is customarily done by other kings.

see further for **too much silver and gold** (3:4), **too much to drink** (3:5), **too many relations with his wives** (3:6).